# Hide a label in a DataList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have defined a label `lblcompname` in `DataList` and it has a constant value. I want to hide this label on page load.

My code,

```
foreach (DataListItem item1 in dlDatalist.Items)
{ 
     Label myTempLabel = (Label)item1.FindControl("lblcompname");
     myTempLabel.Visible = false;
}
```

I tried this code when the page loads, but, `dlDatalist.items` is empty. 
I've also tried this code in `ItemDataBound` of `DataList` but this is also empty.

Comment: how you are binding the datalist? Are you calling this code after the data is binded in datalist?

Comment: No, i call this code on page load. but i have those labels with the harcoded name. This label not required databind of datalist.

Comment: Can you show your mark-up code as well?

Comment: yup.. i solved it out with the ItemDataBound event...